# Can Private IP address be of the form 25. *. *. *

Tags: ip, nat, ipv4

I know that private IP addresses fall into to one of the following ranges:

> (a) 10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255
> (b) 172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255
> (c) 192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255

But when I checked my phone's IP address, this is what I saw:
[image]

IPv4 address in my phone is

> 25.139.3.190

Why has my Internet Service Provider given me this IP address when this is not even a valid private IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question assuming that ISP gives its customers only private IP addresses. Which is not true. ISPs own a range of public IP addresses which they hand over to their customers dynamically.

In my case, `25.139.3.190` was the public IP address which my ISP had given me at that moment. Although my phone had the public IP address using which, theoretically, I could go out on to the internet, yet this IP address `25.139.3.190` is not what the websites I visit see. The websites I visit see the public IP address of the router of my ISP. The ISP's router is using NAT(Network Address Translation) to forward me the packets that belong to me.